# Read and Write Dropbox Files without External Files

Tags: python, dropbox, dropbox-api

All the Dropbox API [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894221/upload-file-to-my-dropbox-from-python-script) and [official documentation](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/start/python) I have seen only give examples of uploading files that are external to Dropbox and then downloading Dropbox files to external files using `put_file` and `get_file` respectively.

Is there a way to both read and write files exclusively in the Dropbox file system without creating external files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send strings directly to `put_file`. It doesn't have to be a file object:

```
# ... insert example code in OP's SO link to get client object

# uploading
s = 'This is a line\n'
s += 'This is another line'
response = client.put_file('/magnum-opus.txt', s)
```

And files received using `get_file` can be already accessed directly without creating an external file:

```
# downloading
f, metadata = client.get_file_and_metadata('/magnum-opus.txt')
for line in f:
    print line
f.close()
```

Comment: You can also just pass a string: `client.put_file('/hello.txt', 'Hello, World!')`

Comment: This is better than using `StringIO`. Updated the answer.