# dropbox API v2 upload large files using python

Tags: python, dropbox-api

I'm trying to upload big file (~900MB) via Dropbox API v2 but I'm getting this error:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.',
>   ConnectionResetError(104, 'Connection reset by peer'))

It works ok with smaller files.

I found in documentation that I need to open upload session using `files_upload_session_start` method but I have an error on this command and I can't go further with `._append` methods.

How can I solve this problem? There're no info in docs.
I'm using Python 3.5.1 and latest dropbox module installed using pip.

Here's code which I'm running to:

```
c = Dropbox(access_token)
f = open("D:\\Programs\\ubuntu-13.10-desktop-amd64.iso", "rb")
result = c.files_upload_session_start(f)
f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END)
size = f.tell()
c.files_upload_session_finish(f,     files.UploadSessionCursor(result.session_id, size), files.CommitInfo("/test900.iso"))
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

For large files like this, you'll need to use upload sessions. Otherwise, you'll run in to issues like the error you posted.

This uses the [Dropbox Python SDK](https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-python) to upload a file to the Dropbox API from the local file as specified by `file_path` to the remote path as specified by `dest_path`. It also chooses whether or not to use an upload session based on the size of the file:

```
import os

from tqdm import tqdm

import dropbox


def upload(
    access_token,
    file_path,
    target_path,
    timeout=900,
    chunk_size=4 * 1024 * 1024,
):
    dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(access_token, timeout=timeout)
    with open(file_path, "rb") as f:
        file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)
        if file_size <= chunk_size:
            print(dbx.files_upload(f.read(), target_path))
        else:
            with tqdm(total=file_size, desc="Uploaded") as pbar:
                upload_session_start_result = dbx.files_upload_session_start(
                    f.read(chunk_size)
                )
                pbar.update(chunk_size)
                cursor = dropbox.files.UploadSessionCursor(
                    session_id=upload_session_start_result.session_id,
                    offset=f.tell(),
                )
                commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path=target_path)
                while f.tell() < file_size:
                    if (file_size - f.tell()) <= chunk_size:
                        print(
                            dbx.files_upload_session_finish(
                                f.read(chunk_size), cursor, commit
                            )
                        )
                    else:
                        dbx.files_upload_session_append(
                            f.read(chunk_size),
                            cursor.session_id,
                            cursor.offset,
                        )
                        cursor.offset = f.tell()
                    pbar.update(chunk_size)
```

Comment: If you get a bytes error in Python 3, I found that using `with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:` instead of `f = open(file_path)` worked for me. Don't forget to indent when using `with`

Comment: It's worth noting that for uploading larger files you may want to initialize Dropbox class object with a `timeout` parameter, eg: `dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(DROPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN, timeout=900)`. The default 30 seconds limit was hit sometimes in my case when the MySQL slave backup grew to around 3GB after a few chunks.

Answer (score 8):

@Greg answer can be updated with Dropbox Api v2 call:

```
self.client.files_upload_session_append_v2(
                f.read(self.CHUNK_SIZE), cursor)
cursor.offset = f.tell()
```

Answer (score 1):

Even though [@Greg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37399658/1207489) is very complete and the nicest solution (and most efficient), I would like to share this minimal implementation for those wanting to quickly learn:

```py
def file_upload(dbx: dropbox.Dropbox, local_path: pathlib.Path, remote_path: str):
    CHUNKSIZE = 100 * 1024 * 1024
    upload_session_start_result = dbx.files_upload_session_start(b'')
    cursor = dropbox.files.UploadSessionCursor(
        session_id=upload_session_start_result.session_id,
        offset=0
    )
    with local_path.open("rb") as f:
        while True:
            data = f.read(CHUNKSIZE)
            if data == b"":
                break
            logger.debug("Pushing %d bytes", len(data))
            dbx.files_upload_session_append_v2(data, cursor)
            cursor.offset += len(data)
    commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path=remote_path)
    dbx.files_upload_session_finish(b'', cursor, commit)
```

It will open a session without sending any data, then in the loop add data, and when there is no more data left, finish. It will do more calls than Greg's answer (in exchange for more readable code).

In python 3.8+ you can use assignment expressions to make this code even nicer (I think):

```py
def file_upload(dbx: dropbox.Dropbox, local_path: pathlib.Path, remote_path: str):
    CHUNKSIZE = 1 * 1024
    upload_session_start_result = dbx.files_upload_session_start(b'')
    cursor = dropbox.files.UploadSessionCursor(
        session_id=upload_session_start_result.session_id,
        offset=0
    )
    with local_path.open("rb") as f:
        while (data := f.read(CHUNKSIZE)) != b"":
            logger.debug("Pushing %d bytes", len(data))
            dbx.files_upload_session_append_v2(data, cursor)
            cursor.offset += len(data)
    commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path=remote_path)
    dbx.files_upload_session_finish(b'', cursor, commit)
```