# Uploading Large Files to Dropbox using Dropbox API and Python Results in Error

Tags: python, file-upload, dropbox-api

I am trying to upload a large zipped file to Dropbox (about 2-3GB) using Python and the Dropbox API v2. I am using the "chunked method" found here: [dropbox API v2 upload large files using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37397966/dropbox-api-v2-upload-large-files-using-python). Here is the code again for convenience:

```
f = open(file_path)
file_size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

CHUNK_SIZE = 4 * 1024 * 1024

if file_size <= CHUNK_SIZE:

    print dbx.files_upload(f, dest_path)

else:

    upload_session_start_result = dbx.files_upload_session_start(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE))
    cursor = dropbox.files.UploadSessionCursor(session_id=upload_session_start_result.session_id,
                                               offset=f.tell())
    commit = dropbox.files.CommitInfo(path=dest_path)

    while f.tell() < file_size:
        if ((file_size - f.tell()) <= CHUNK_SIZE):
            print dbx.files_upload_session_finish(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE),
                                            cursor,
                                            commit)
        else:
            dbx.files_upload_session_append(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE),
                                            cursor.session_id,
                                            cursor.offset)
            cursor.offset = f.tell()
```

However, when I run it I am getting a

> dropbox.exceptions.APIError

as well as

> UploadSessoionLookupError

and a

> UploadSessionOffsetError

I think the error might be occurring at this line specifically:

```
 dbx.files_upload_session_append(f.read(CHUNK_SIZE),
                                       cursor.session_id,
                                       cursor.offset)
```

I've tried swapping that for

```
dbx.files_upload_session_append_v2(
                f.read(self.CHUNK_SIZE), cursor)
```

but that didn't work either. Any suggestions?

Comment: `APIError`, `UploadSessionLookupError`, and `UploadSessionOffsetError` are just the error types. They should contain more information, so make sure you check the full error for more information on the issue.

Comment: The `UploadSessionLookupError` gave me "incorrect_offset" while `UploadSessionOffesetError` gave me "correct_offset = 10000" I still don't know what to do with that information though.

Comment: Did you also post on the Dropbox forum? I just replied there with more information on that: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/Uploading-large-files-using-chunks/m-p/249182#M14309

Answer (score 0):

On windows, be sure to open using binary mode

```
f = open(file_path, 'rb')
```

`f.read(chunk_size)` and `f.tell()` were off.

from python docs

> On Windows, `tell()` can return illegal values (after an `fgets()`) when reading files with Unix-style line-endings. Use binary mode (`‘rb’`) to circumvent this problem.