# how to integrate a django project to a cloud storage

Tags: python, django, cloud, webfaction

I have a running `Django application` running on `webfaction server`. I want to integrate my django project with a cloud storage system. How can I Integrate that ?

Here is the detail about my app:
It is an `erp software` in django. It has a app named `Projects`. In that app, it has a `model` name `Project`.

```
  class Project(BaseModel):
        event = models.ForeignKey("events.Event")
        client = models.ForeignKey("clients.Client")
        project_supervisor = models.ForeignKey("staffs.Staff", blank=True, null=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        project_number = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
        currency = models.ForeignKey("projects.Currency")
        hall_number = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        stand_number = models.CharField(max_length=128)
        start_date = models.DateField()
        end_date = models.DateField()
        notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        terms_and_conditions = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
        is_design_required = models.BooleanField(choices=BOOL_CHOICES, default=False)
        status = models.CharField(max_length=128, choices=PROJECT_STATUS, default="pending")
        admin_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_quote_send = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_estimate_send = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

I want add an extra field to this model to store the project details.And I want to upload these pictures in the cloud, say dropbox or google , and want to upload it through django.That means I want to store that document field only in a cloud database? Is that possible in DJANGO?

Answer (score 2):

To see the detail please see this stackoverflow [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894221/upload-file-to-my-dropbox-from-python-script/36851978#36851978)
and the source code with APP v2 to upload file on dropbox is.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dropbox

class TransferData:
    def __init__(self, access_token):
        self.access_token = access_token

    def upload_file(self, file_from, file_to):
        """upload a file to Dropbox using API v2
        """
        dbx = dropbox.Dropbox(self.access_token)

        with open(file_from, 'rb') as f:
            dbx.files_upload(f.read(), file_to)

def main():
    access_token = '******'
    transferData = TransferData(access_token)

    file_from = 'test.txt'
    file_to = '/test_dropbox/test.txt'  # The full path to upload the file to, including the file name

    # API v2
    transferData.upload_file(file_from, file_to)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The source code is hosted on GitHub [code link](https://github.com/sparkandshine/tools/tree/master/dropbox/transferdata) and to get dropbox access token see this [link](https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2014/05/generate-an-access-token-for-your-own-account/)

Comment: I'm asking about  a specific field in a model to drop box.. Not the entire database.. All other fields are there in postgresql