# Uploading files to dropbox using python with the access tokens

Tags: python, upload, dropbox

How can I upload files to Dropbox in python using access tokens?

I have tried with the following code for uploading the file

```
import requests
import json
print("uploading")
token ='#######'
para = {"path": "folder/file.txt", "mode": "add", "autorename": "true", "mute": "false", "strict_conflict": "false"}
headers = {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token}
files = {'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'), 'file': open("file.txt", "rb")}
response = requests.post("https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/upload", headers=headers, files=files)
```

I got an error in response like this:

Error in call to API function "files/upload": Must provide HTTP header "Dropbox-API-Arg" or URL parameter "arg".

How can I modify the code for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [upload file to my dropbox from python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894221/upload-file-to-my-dropbox-from-python-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following header and read the [docs](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-upload) to update your request with the necessary headers:

```
import json
headers["Dropbox-API-Arg"] = json.dumps({"path": "folder/file.txt", "mode": "add", "autorename": true, "mute": false, "strict_conflict": false})
headers["Content-Type"] = "application/octet-stream"
```

Comment: headers["Dropbox-API-Arg"] = {\"path\": \"/folder/file.txt\", \"mode\": \"add\", \"autorename\": true, \"mute\": false,\"strict_conflict\": false}"
                                                                                                                                                       
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
@cullzie I got this as error

Comment: After that also same error,   
`headers["Dropbox-API-Arg"] = {\"path\": \"folder/file.txt\", \"mode\": \"add\", \"autorename\": true, \"mute\": false, \"strict_conflict\": false}`
                                                                                                                                                       
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

Comment: Updated to remove the backslashes

Comment: I got this error,    requests.exceptions InvalidHeader: Value for header `{Dropbox-API-Arg: {'path': 'folder/file.txt', 'mute': 'false', 'mode': 'add', 'strict_conflict': 'false', 'autorename': 'true'}}`  must be of type str or bytes, not <type 'dict'>